# I have questions about Webhooks and payment plan

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

1 Webhooks provides only events when customers successfully trade. But if the customer cancels the subscription on the device (that is, terminating Recurring billing?) Will webhook call my site? Where is the webhook of the action, where is the detailed information?

2 There is a demand for our business, that is, the probation period. It is the customer who pays the "trial fee" (instant payment) for a week. After that, if the customer does not cancel the subscription, we will charge the actual fee (charge every month's payment plan).I don't know if there is any corresponding solution.

Look forward to your reply

Answer (score 0):

1. The webhook URL is called only when there is a successful payment and also when the status of an initiated transfer is successful.  If a subscription is cancelled, we will stop charging the users card and the `status` will be updated to `cancel`. So you have to use `Cron Job` to check the subscription status on the due dates.
2. You can charge your trial fee at the first charge and the payment plan ID to the payload. So when next its due, the charges the actual monthly amount.